Set up Ubuntu server on VirtualBox with Vagrant & Ansible via another Ubuntu existing server
Might sound stupid, but anyway..
Got this idea to try and raise another Ubuntu server into VirtualBox and learn some automation with Vagrant and Ansible instead of installing each and every tool I would possibly need manually. But the thing is I run VirtualBox on a Windows host and already have another Ubuntu server as my playground.
Would it be somehow possible to use the existing Ubuntu server from inside the VB to create another one on it? Don't want to bother with WSL or Windows to do these things.
